# Having problems getting form values from dropdowns populated from 2 arrays

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms, form-submit

The Staff array contains the names of staff with a unique ID.
The roster array uses the unique ID to determine which staff was on that day.

I'm trying to get an updated 'roster' array sent when submit is pressed, however I don't seem to be able to get any values from the form. I'm doing something stupid, but I can't see the forrest for the trees.

```
$roster array 
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => date
        [1] => id[s]
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 25/12/2017-31/12/2017
        [1] => 1
        [2] => 2
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 01/01/2018-07/01/2018
        [1] => 2
        [2] => 3
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 08/01/2018-14/01/2018
        [1] => 2
        [2] => 1
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => 15/01/2018-21/01/2018
        [1] => 8
        [2] => 1
        [3] => 3
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [0] => 22/01/2018-28/01/2018
        [1] => 2
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [0] => 29/01/2018-04/02/2018
        [1] => 2
        [2] => 1
    )

)

$staff array
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [Team] => RED
        [Name] => Person A
        [ID] => 001
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Team] => BLUE
        [Name] => Person B
        [ID] => 002
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [Team] => RED
        [Name] => Person C
        [ID] => 003
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [Team] => BLUE
        [Name] => Person D
        [ID] => 004
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [Team] => RED
        [Name] => Person E
        [ID] => 005
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [Team] => Test Group
        [Name] => Test Person
        [ID] => 006
    )

 )

<?php
$teams=array();
$last = count($staff) - 1;
foreach ($staff as $i => $row)
{
    $isFirst = ($i == 0);
    $isLast = ($i == $last);
    array_push($teams,$row['Team']); //push all teams into on array to find the number of teams in total
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($roster);

print_r($staff);

print_r($teams);

echo "</pre>";
$uniqueteams=array_unique($teams);

echo '<form method="post" action="save.php" id="rosterform">';

echo '<table border="1"><tr id="heading">';
//print the team names
print "<td>Week&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Date</td>";
foreach ($uniqueteams as $i)
  {
  print "<td>".$i."</td>".PHP_EOL;
  }
echo "</tr>";

foreach (range(0, 52) as $wknumber) {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>";
  echo "week ".$wknumber;
  echo "</td>";

  foreach ($uniqueteams as $i)
    {
    echo "<td><div><select name=\"rostered\">".PHP_EOL;
    foreach ($staff as $j => $row){
      if ($row['Team']==$i){
         echo '<option value="'.$row['ID'].'">'.$row['Name'].'</option>'.PHP_EOL;
         }
      }
    echo "</select></div></td>".PHP_EOL;
    }
 }
echo '</table>';
//save the roster.csv file back
echo '<input type="submit" name="save" value="save">';
echo '</form>';

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can't get any data where? In save.php?

Comment: @Daz i think u get only one value in save.php

Comment: @ProEvilz, yes, in save.php is just <pre><?php var_dump($_POST);?></pre>    . I get nothing from the dropdowns being sent

Comment: @Kevin Antala, yes, I get what appears to be the single end value of the staff array. I expected to get the entire array

Comment: u need to replace this <select name=\"rostered\"> with <select name=\"rostered.$wknumber\"[]> i think u get your desire output

Comment: @Kevin Antala, getting closer. I get the full 'set of an array now, but the values are always the last value of the staff array, not what is chosen in the dropdowns.   ["rostered_0"]=>
  string(3) "006"
  ["rostered_1"]=>
  string(3) "006"
  ["rostered_2"]=>
  string(3) "006"

Comment: ok u need to replace this <select name=\"rostered\"> with <select name='rostered".$wknumber."[]'> and think now ur problem solve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ($uniqueteams as $i)
    {
        echo "<td><div><select name='rostered".$wknumber."[]'>".PHP_EOL;
        foreach ($staff as $j => $row){
            if ($row['Team']==$i){
                echo '<option value="'.$row['ID'].'">'.$row['Name'].'</option>'.PHP_EOL;
            }
        }
        echo "</select></div></td>".PHP_EOL;
    }
```